# IRQCHIP_DECLARE: init function is not being run

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, xilinx

I am trying to use the Xilinx interrupt controller driver in an embedded ARM FPGA system I am developing.
  (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/irqchip/irq-xilinx-intc.c)

At the end of this driver is the line:

`IRQCHIP_DECLARE(xilinx_intc_xps, "xlnx,xps-intc-1.00.a", xilinx_intc_of_init);`

I have added an entry in my device tree for the interrupt controller.

```
    xil_intc: xil_intc@41810000 {           
        compatible = "xlnx,xps-intc-1.00.a";                                    
        interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
        interrupts = <0x0 0x1e 0x04>;
        reg = <0x41810000 0x10000>;
        interrupt-controller;
        #interrupt-cells = <2>;
        xlnx,kind-of-intr = <0x0>;
        xlnx,num-intr-inputs = <0x1>;
    };
```

However, from what I can tell, the `xilinx_intc_of_init` function is never called during startup.  I added a `pr_info` at the beginning of the function, but I never see it called.

The only message that seems to indicate an issue is:

`[    0.177772] irq: no irq domain found for /amba/xil_intc@41810000 !`

I have successfully written and compiled other device drivers, added entries in the device tree, and had them load up and show in `dmesg`, but for some reason I can't get this one to work.

Any suggestions on debugging this?

For what it's worth, I'm compiling the driver into a kernel module, installing using `modules_install` and have added an entry to `/etc/modules` to load it on startup.

Edit: I am using a 4.6 kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IRQCHIP_DECLARE(xilinx_intc_xps, "xlnx,xps-intc-1.00.a", xilinx_intc_of_init);
```

The driver `irq-xilinx-intc.c` is using the above call to register with the irq subsystem.

If irq driver uses `IRQCHIP_DECLARE` macro it will follow the below sequence to invoke the `xilinx_intc_of_init()` (callback function)

```
start_kernel() –> init_IRQ() --> irqchip_init() --> of_irq_init() --> call-back function (xilinx_intc_of_init)
```

If The Driver was registered using `IRQCHIP_DECLARE`  it must be compiled into the kernel and the callback function will be invoked at kernel boot time.

It doesn't work as kernel modules/overlay like other device drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I came to the conclusion that loading the irqchip driver from /lib/modules was too late in the boot process.

I ended up rebuilding the entire kernel with a modified configuration to include this driver, and then the initialization worked properly.

I guess the lesson is that IRQCHIP drivers must be compiled into the kernel and don't work as kernel modules like other device drivers?  I can't find any documentation that says so, but that's the behavior I observed.